# How to determine normalcy for a one group pre-test post-test?

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption, pre-post-comparison, shapiro-wilk-test

My study is a retrospective one group pre-test post-test on multiple variables. Not every patient in the study had scores for all of the variables, so as long as a patient had both a pretest and a paired posttest, the pair was included. That left different paired totals for each variable. I'd like to conduct a paired t-test for each variable, but I am confused as how to determine normalcy (I'm assuming I should). If I'm correct, I should be using Shapiro–Wilk - all of the variables have totals in the low 20s, with one of them under 20. My question, is what value should I be conducting the Shapiro Wilk (if that is the correct test) on, the pre-test values, or the differences between the pre-test and post test values?

Comment: A paired *t*-test is conducted as a one-sample *t*-test where (*pre* - *post*) is the analyzed variable.  The *pre* observations and *post* observations as such aren't considered in the analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So if I understand you correctly, I am looking for normalcy of the (pre-post) variables.